# Show that a function is not in the range of the operator $T$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

> Show that $f(t)=e^t$ are not in the range of the operator
> $$T(g)(t)=\int_{-1}^{1}(t-s)^2g(s)ds$$
> I suppose that exists a function $h(t)$ such that $T(h)t=e^t$ and i try to work without and use the fundamental theorem of calculus of something similar but i dont see, the hint of the book is "you can use the closed range theorem".
> Any hint or suggestion i will be very grateful.
> Thanks

Comment: What is the domain of $T$?

Comment: the continous functions on $[-1,1]$

Comment: Did you notice that $Tg$ is a quadratic polynomial for any $g$?